# Can you explain the meaning of sentence and the word "run"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am not the native English reader.
I want to know what the "sentence 3" means, especially with the meaning of "run."
The reason why I quoted "sentence 1" and "sentence 2" is to help you understand the context of the sentence 3. By these parts are included in the article about teacher evaluation. Thank you for your help.

- sentence 1:
  Thus, a teacher who appears to be very ineffective in one year might have a dramatically different result the following year.
- sentence 2: 
  The same dramatic fluctuations were found for teachers ranked at the bottom in the first year of analysis.

**- sentence 3:** 
This **runs** counter to most people’s notions that the true quality of a teacher is likely to change very little over time and raises questions about whether what is measured is largely a “teacher effect” or the effect of a wide variety of other factors.

Comment: The closest meaning of "runs" here is "works". As in "it works counter to the popular notion.."

Answer (score 2):

In this context ***runs counter to*** would mean the same as ***contradicts*** or  ***goes against***.

*Counter* here means *against* as in *counter* clockwise, *counter* argument, *counter* intuitive. To *run counter to* is to *move against* or *oppose*.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand "counter" is the center of this phrase.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble understanding the meaning of one word, try to expanding your search in the dictionary to a phrase. In this case, if we look up "run counter", we will certainly stumble upon what we need. A definition from [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/run-counter-to):

> **run counter to**
>
> to have a contrary effect or action to

So we can rephrase the sentence as:

> This does not conform to most people’s notions...

or

> This is quite the opposite to most people’s notions...

Comment: Thank you very much. Collins is very good at searching complex phrase, so it would be useful for my English study. Thank you again.